# Google Analytics event count data not accurate

Tags: google-analytics, keycloak, gtag.js

Here at my company they have embedded g-tags on their website, there's an event which tracks logins BUT the data does not matches with the number of events i recieve in postgress DB.
I also get events in post-gres DB because they also use keycloack so the login data is also logged in keycloack postgres DB.
here is a sample of 2 days data.

**day 1= >**

- keycloack DB : 370
- google analytics : 1.2k

**day 2 =>**

- keycloack DB : 351
- google analytics : 1.1k

etc etc

As we can see its a BIG difference, anyone else had this kind of problem? specifically in regard to keycloack data reflection on goolge analytics. Can it be due to event repetion i.e g-tags might be triggerering events multiple times.

i treid but the difference doesnt seems constant to me.